# How to calculate the SQNR of the PCM system in dB?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, snr

Assume that the input *signal **S(t)*** is sinusoidal with *amplitude **A*** and quantized to **R** number of binary bits, how can I calculate the ***SQNR*** of the **PCM** system in **dB**? I know that the output *signal-to-quantizing-noise ratio* (SQNR) in a PCM system is the same as the ratio of the *average-signal power* to the *average-quantization-noise power*.

$$SQNR_{PCM}=\frac{P_{AvgS}}{P_{AvgQN}}$$

I know that \$P_{AvgS}={σ_x}^2\$ but how about \$P_{AvgQN}\$? *Average-noise power* (\$\frac{Δ^2}{12}\$) seems not the same as *average-quantization-noise power* since the answer should not be 1.76+6.02R when using this.

---

***Thank you for your attention.***

Comment: [This answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66261/signal-to-noise-ratio-problem/66274#66274) should be helpful.